# Why is my ghost variable havoc'd when it has an axiom?

Tags: certora

In Certora, I have the following ghost variable:

```js
ghost mathint listingUpdatesCount {
    init_state axiom listingUpdatesCount == 0;
}
```

So, my `listingUpdatesCount` should start as 0, and not be `HAVAC`'d. However, after running my formal verification, I see in the logs:

```
-----listingUpdatesCount: 1         HAVOC
```

How is it possible that the variable updates in a havoc'd way?

### More Context

I have these two hooks:

```js
hook Sstore s_listings[KEY address nftAddress][KEY uint256 tokenId].price uint256 price STORAGE {
    listingUpdatesCount = listingUpdatesCount + 1;
}

hook LOG4(uint offset, uint length, bytes32 t1, bytes32 t2, bytes32 t3, bytes32 t4) uint v {
    listingUpdatesCount = listingUpdatesCount - 1;
}
```

And it shouldn't be possible for `listingUpdatesCount` to ever be 1. The counterexample certora gives doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption that `init_state axiom` should prevent `listingUpdatesCount` from starting as 0 is inaccurate. What `init_state axiom` does is require that the axiom is held when the constructor is called. For all other states, nothing is assumed about the ghost variable unless you're proving an invariant which has some property about this ghost or have an explicit require in a rule.

You'll want to make sure that whatever functions your working with don't havoc. Havocing functions can reset your ghost variables to random anythings.

One way to do that, would be to set your functions to a true dispatcher. This means the prover won't assume you're working with contracts outside those included in the prover run.

```js
function _.functionName() external => DISPATCHER(true)
```